# How to export code on Origami Studio

Tags: ios, facebook, origami

I have download Origami Studio

[image]

And i have download the moments onboarding :

http://origami.design/examples/moments-onboarding-original.html

I wish to export the code but i don't find where i can do it...

Comment: Facing same issue :( Have you find any.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 3):

The 'Export to Code' feature was very much present in Origami 2.0. In the release of Origami Studio, however, it was silently removed.